# Why can't I have a Google+/Quora style ability to follow a user in Stack[Overflow/Exchange] sites?

Tags: feature-request

I am interested in following a few people who have a huge reputation in a particular field (for example Unix), so that I can get informed everytime they contribute to Stack[Overflow/Exchange] sites, so that I can go get enlightened. In short, I want to be an official follower of such experts.

Comment: Stack exchange is not a social network,  nor does it wish to be

Comment: If you want to follow a user's contributions, you can follow their RSS feed linked at the bottom right of their profile page.

Comment: The experts probably do not want to be followed.

Comment: @BilltheLizard- Thanks a lot and you are the first one, whose feed I have subscribed to.Thanks again.

Comment: Look, I told you to stop stalking me.

Answer (score 7):

We are not a social network. We are a Question and Answer website.

Having more social features of this sort would take away the focus of the site.

Comment: This, and I am not sure that Jon Skeet would want that much of a fan club

Comment: I was wrong in phrasing my question.@BilltheLizard has got the point and answered it correctly.Thanks though.